# Div background-color goes blank after adding id

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/RMMJe/

```
    #test1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width:960px;
    height:1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }


<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="csswenqin.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="test1">
<p>
Hello
</p>
</div>
</body>
```

It works perfectly, until I add an id to the div. I'm not quite sure why, could someone help me out please? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your fiddle is flawed.

Comment: In your Fiddle, the CSS is in the Javascript field

Comment: Oh just realized that, thank you!

Comment: works just fine, if you put the css in the correct place: http://jsfiddle.net/RMMJe/1/

Comment: I get a blue background.

Comment: You're not accidentally applying an id that happens to have a style in the stylesheet file?

Comment: Use firebug or browser developer tools on the `div` to find out what styles may affect the div's background in your environment

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your CSS code is in the right place, then it should work fine. Changing the background color using Javascript would be something else entirely.